# Getting Access Denied After Successfully upload the multiple Files

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

Getting Access Denied After Successfully upload the multiple Files.

This is the error I'm getting when I upload multiple files:

naser.jpg naseer.new.pdf naseer.new.docx errorjava.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\srinu (Access is denied)

Where naser.jpg naseer.new.pdf naseer.new.docx are the file name I've uploaded.

I'm unable to find the error, can anyone help me find the mistake please.

```
Eduvationservletimp

import java.io.File;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.servlet.http.Part;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/UploadServlet"})

@MultipartConfig(fileSizeThreshold = 1024 * 1024 * 10, maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 50, maxRequestSize = 1024 * 1024 * 100)

public class EducationServletimp extends HttpServlet {

    private static final String education = null;

// this if directory name where the file will be uploaded and saved



// this is the method which is created by system it self

protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

throws ServletException, IOException {

response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

// this tyr is created by me for the connection of database

try {

// this is the path provide by me to save the image

  //     HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
  //  String uname=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");


    // HttpSession session=request.getSession(false);
  // String uname=(String)session.getAttribute("uname");

String savePath = "d:/srinu";
/*in place of C: you can place a path wher you need to save the image*/

// this comment will picup the image file and have convert it into file type

File fileSaveDir = new File(savePath);

if (!fileSaveDir.exists()) {

fileSaveDir.mkdirs();

}

// this two comment will take the name and image form web page

String sscboard =request.getParameter("sscboard");
String schoolname =request.getParameter("schoolname");
String percentagein =request.getParameter("percentagein");
String percentage =request.getParameter("percentage");
String passedout =request.getParameter("passedout");
String ssccountry =request.getParameter("ssccountry");
String sscstate =request.getParameter("sscstate");
String sscdistrict =request.getParameter("sscdistrict"); 
Part sscmemo = request.getPart("sscmemo");


String interboard =request.getParameter("interboard");
String intercollege =request.getParameter("intercollege");
String interpercentage =request.getParameter("interpercentage");
String interbranch =request.getParameter("interbranch");
String interpassedout =request.getParameter("interpassedout");
String intercountry =request.getParameter("intercountry");
String interstate =request.getParameter("interstate");
String interdistrict =request.getParameter("interdistrict"); 
Part intermemo = request.getPart("intermemo");




String degree =request.getParameter("degree");
String university =request.getParameter("university");
String collegename =request.getParameter("collegename");
String branch =request.getParameter("branch");
String degreepassedout =request.getParameter("degreepassedout");
String degreepercentage =request.getParameter("degreepercentage");
String degreecountry =request.getParameter("degreecountry");
String degreestate =request.getParameter("degreestate");
String degreedistrict =request.getParameter("degreedistrict"); 
Part cmm = request.getPart("cmm");



String pguniversity =request.getParameter("pguniversity");
String pgcollege =request.getParameter("pgcollege");
String pgbranch =request.getParameter("pgbranch");
String pgpassedout =request.getParameter("pgpassedout");
String pgpercentage =request.getParameter("pgpercentage");
String pgcountry =request.getParameter("pgcountry");
String pgstate =request.getParameter("pgstate");
String pgdistrict =request.getParameter("pgdistrict"); 
Part pgmemo = request.getPart("pgmemo");

// this comment will extract the file name of image

String fileName = extractFileName(sscmemo);
String fileName1 = extractFileName(intermemo);
String fileName2 = extractFileName(cmm);
String fileName3 = extractFileName(pgmemo);




// this will print the image name and user provide name

out.println(fileName);
out.println(fileName1);
out.println(fileName2);
out.println(fileName3);




//out.println("\n" + name);

/*if you may have more than one files with same name then you can calculate

some random characters and append that characters in fileName so that it will

make your each image name identical.*/

sscmemo.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);
intermemo.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName1);
cmm.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName2);
pgmemo.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName3);


/*

You need this loop if you submitted more than one file

for (Part part : request.getParts()) {

String fileName = extractFileName(part);

part.write(savePath + File.separator + fileName);

}*/

// connectio to database

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/verification","root","toor");

// query to insert name and image name

String query = "INSERT INTO education(sscmemo,intermemo,cmm,pgmemo) values(?,?,?,?)";

PreparedStatement pst;

pst = con.prepareStatement(query);

pst.setString(1, sscboard);
pst.setString(2, schoolname);
pst.setString(3, percentagein);
pst.setString(4, percentage);
pst.setString(5, passedout);
pst.setString(6, ssccountry);
pst.setString(7, sscstate);
pst.setString(8, sscdistrict); 
String filePath = savePath + File.separator + fileName;
pst.setString(1, filePath);



pst.setString(10, interboard);
pst.setString(11, intercollege);
pst.setString(12, interpercentage);
pst.setString(13, interbranch);
pst.setString(14, interpassedout);
pst.setString(15, intercountry);
pst.setString(16, interstate);
pst.setString(17, interdistrict); 
String filePath1 = savePath + File.separator + fileName1;
pst.setString(2, filePath1);




pst.setString(19, degree);
pst.setString(20, university);
pst.setString(21, collegename);
pst.setString(22, branch);
pst.setString(23, degreepassedout);
pst.setString(24, degreepercentage);
pst.setString(25, degreecountry);
pst.setString(26, degreestate);
pst.setString(27, degreedistrict);
String filePath2 = savePath + File.separator + fileName2;
pst.setString(3, filePath2);


pst.setString(29, pguniversity);
pst.setString(30, pgcollege);
pst.setString(31, pgbranch);
pst.setString(32, pgpassedout);
pst.setString(33, pgpercentage);
pst.setString(34, pgcountry);
pst.setString(35, pgstate);
pst.setString(36, pgdistrict);
String filePath3 = savePath + File.separator + fileName3;
pst.setString(4, filePath3);



int i=pst.executeUpdate();  
if(i>0) {
    out.print("<p>Record saved successfully!</p>");  
}else{  
    out.println("Sorry! unable to save record");  
} 





} catch (Exception ex) {

out.println("error" + ex);

}

}

}

// the extractFileName() is method used to extract the file name

private String extractFileName(Part part) {

String contentDisp = part.getHeader("content-disposition");

String[] items = contentDisp.split(";");

for (String s : items) {

if (s.trim().startsWith("filename")) {

return s.substring(s.indexOf("=") + 2, s.length() - 1);

}

}

return "";

}

@Override

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

throws ServletException, IOException {

processRequest(request, response);

}

@Override

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

throws ServletException, IOException {

processRequest(request, response);

}

@Override

public String getServletInfo() {

return "Short description";

}

}
```

Pleas provide  solution.
Thank You

Comment: "Pleas provide solution." - we're not a do-my-work service but we can try to help _you_ find a solution. How many files is "many"? How much space is left on the partion?

Comment: 3 file, space 10gb

Comment: Btw, please provide a [mcve] - I feel the code you've posted contains way too much clutter (e.g. request parameter handling, db queries etc. which are not related to the file handling problem you describe)

Comment: Yes ,But due to that data not store in database . i will past the entire code

Comment: That's still irrelevant because the problem you describe will cause the exception and thus problems further down the line. Think of how this presents itself to us: there's a lot of clutter and instead of removing that you tell us to find spot the problem in that heap of code. Do you think we'll be inclined to do so?

Comment: Also please provide the _entire_ stacktrace you get and mark the lines of your code that are mentioned there so we don't have to guess. Speaking of guesses: you seem to try and extract 4 file names from the request, what happens when one is missing and you get an empty string for that parameter? You'd then try to write to the directory itself (`savePath + File.separator + fileName` would result to `d:/srinu/`) which of course can't work.

Comment: but its working, when ever i am trying to upload the files in to folder and database ,files will b stored in folder(3 or 4) but data will not stored ,in the database and it shows error like that   naser.jpg naseer.new.pdf naseer.new.docx errorjava.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: d:\srinu (Access is denied)

Comment: The database transaction will most likely not be committed or be rolled back when you get the exception, hence the data will not be present in the database. The filesystem doesn't have transactions though so any changes like moving files that happend before the exception will be kept - that's why you see the files being uploaded and moved.